# How to solve an equation which contains an integral and 2 parameters

Tags: matlab, parameters, equation, symbolic-integration

This is an example of a system of equations which I would like to solve.
[equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o05q1.png)

a and b must be selected in such a way that the results of these integrals are 0.
But I don't know

- how to integrate with parameters
- how to solve a system of equations if I can't write it like Ax=b. If so I could solve it with x = A\b

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't solve the integrals analytically, you can use `int` with `syms` to get an expression of the integrals.

```
syms x a b;
f = a*(x-8)^3 + b*(x-6)^5;
F = int(f, 0, 1);
```

which you can find the roots of by `solve`

```
solve(F, [a b])
```

Comparing the roots for each equation would tell you if there is an `a` and `b` that solves the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Integration is linear, so the parameters can immediately just be pulled out.  You have `a * I1 + b * I2 = 0` and `a * I3 + b * I4 = 0` in your example, where `I1` is the integral from 0 to 1 of (x-8)^3, etc.

The integrands in this case are trivial polynomials (monomials even after u-substitution).  You can easily evaluate the integrals by hand, though it's simple here to just observe that all must be nonzero.  Hence you've got a general linear system of the form `A * [a, b]' = 0` with all the entries in `A` nonzero.  Aside from a degenerate system (which this case isn't), then the only solution is `a = b = 0`.

In general, assuming you have the possibility of a nonzero right-hand side, you'll use the same idea.  Distribute the integration over the parameters, getting a system of equations with parameters being multiplied by constants that are the values of the non-parameterized integrals.  Evaluate the integrals, either analytically or numerically.  Solve the resulting system of equations in the usual way, with just `A \ rhs` if the system is always linear in the parameters.